# Add GAS Library programmatically?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to add a GAS library script programmatically? I'm making a gdoc with a script and pasting in some information, but I think it would be better to have that info in a sidebar controlled by a central library. (I know that creating it as an addon is also possible).

Comment: Libraries are listing in the appsscript.json manifest file. See: [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/dependencies](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/dependencies) And you can edit the manifest file programmatically by using the [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent)  You'd need to know the file ID of the Apps Script project that is bound to the Doc, and I don't think that you can't get that programmatically.

Comment: The following GitHub code may be of interest to you: [https://github.com/RomainVialard/Push-new-version-of-library-to-given-set-of-projects](https://github.com/RomainVialard/Push-new-version-of-library-to-given-set-of-projects)